# iOS fails to keep UITableViewCell select when style is custom in Edit Mode

Tags: ios, uitableview

If I use tableviewcell with style basic, I can keep my checkbox stay selected.

But if I change to style custom, I can still select in the edit mode but checkbox selected never stay....

I a using swift 3

Update: I want to achieve mail app in edit mode where I can select/deselect multi selection.

I found myself below method was called

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

But the isSelect is always false
[Edit Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjtJb.png)

If uitableviewcell style .basic the checkbox(isSelect) true, but style .custom, it is just always false

Comment: post your code work and UI screen shot so that we can understand your problem

Comment: question is not clear what is your issue.

Comment: I cannot reach my sourcecode atm. Let me try to explain in text.  What i want to achieve is mail app editmode where a default checkbox on the left and can select multi row of data. If tableviewcell use style custom, i cannot keep the selected on, as soon as finger up, selected goes off

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
```

I have to implement above in the uitableviewcell.swift file

Comment: with uitableviewcell style .basic, I need no extra swift file. But style custom required to extra swift file

Answer (score 0):

Once try to set `tintColor` for your `tableView` in `viewDidload` like,

```
self.yourTableView.tintColor =  [UIColor blueColor];
```

**Swift :**

Something like,

```
self.yourTableView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

It's because you have set custom cell style so that your `UITableView` is not getting default properties like `tintColor` !!

Comment: I can see the selected code and the default checkbox change state, but the state wont stay as selected, so i think the problem is not this